# Invalid use of incomplete type "class..."

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I keep getting this error and I don't understand what I do wrong: " error: invalid use of incomplete type '**class Auftrag**'" at method **getAuftraeg()** where I want to print the "**vpa**" list. Please help me!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Auftrag;

class Kunde {
public:
    Kunde(Kunde *kunde) {
        *this = kunde;
    }

    Kunde(string s) : name{s}, vpa{} {}

    void print(){
        cout<<this->name<<endl;
        getAuftraege();
    }

    string getName() const { return name; }

    void addAuftrag(Auftrag *auftrag){
        this->vpa.push_back(auftrag);
    }

    void getAuftraege() {
        for (int i{0};i<vpa.size();i++)
            cout << this->vpa.at(i)->getID();
    }

    private:
        string name;
        vector<Auftrag*> vpa;
};

class Auftrag {
public:
    Auftrag(string s) : id{s}, pk{nullptr} {}

    void print() {
        cout<<this->id<<endl;
    }
    string getID() const { return id; }
    void setKunde(Kunde *kunde){
        this->pk = kunde;
    }
    Kunde *getKunde() const;
    private:
    string id;
    Kunde *pk;
};


int main() {
    // Anlegen: zwei Kunden und drei Auftraege
    Kunde *k1{new Kunde{"Sepplhuber-Finsterwalder"}};
    Kunde k2{"Kurz"};
    Auftrag *a1{new Auftrag{"Decke streichen"}};
    Auftrag *a2{new Auftrag{"Wand tapezieren"}};
    Auftrag a3{"Jalousie montieren"};
    Auftrag a4{"Laminat verlegen"};
    // Erste Assoziationsrichtung:
    // aus einem Objekt vom Typ Kunde
    // zu Objekten vom Typ Auftrag
    k1->addAuftrag(a1);
    k1->addAuftrag(a2);
    k1->addAuftrag(&a3);
    // Zweite Assoziationsrichtung:
    // aus einem Objekt vom Typ Auftrag
    // zu einem Objekt vom Typ Kunde
    a4.setKunde(&k2);
    // Alles ausgeben:
    k1->print();
    k2.print();
    a1->print();
    a2->print();
    a3.print();
    a4.print();
    // Speicher zurueckgeben:
    delete k1;
    k1 = nullptr;
    delete a1;
    a1 = nullptr;
    delete a2;
    a2 = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: How is the compiler supposed to know if `Auftrag` even has a method named `getID`, if it can't see `class`' definition?

Comment: `*this = kunde;` What is this supposed to do? Did you want to implement a copy constructor instead?

Answer (score 1):

Place the function definitions after the definition of the class `Auftrag`.

For example

```
inline void  Kunde ::addAuftrag(Auftrag *auftrag){
    this->vpa.push_back(auftrag);
}

inline void  Kunde ::getAuftraege() {
    for (int i{0};i<vpa.size();i++)
        cout << this->vpa.at(i)->getID();
}
```

The compiler has to know the definition of the class `Auftrag` that to determine that it has such a data member as `vpa`.